# How to launch a VSCode extension with a new file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a VSCode extension and since it should currently only run on JS files, when I run the Launch Extension task I want it to open with a new Javascript file. I've seen [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832729/how-to-add-a-new-file-to-the-workspace-when-developing-a-new-vscode-extension) and have tried adding, just passing an `options` object as per the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_workspace)

```
 vscode.workspace.openTextDocument({language: 'javascript'})
```

This is an async call so I've tried `await`ing it while my extension is activating to ensure the file exists before I am able to use my extension.

If I could add this functionality to the Launch Extension task that'd be great or even if I could just have it open a file when I run my command that'll do while I'm developing on it.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure but I believe your extension is activated only once and stays like that until vscode shuts down. Hence you cannot trigger multiple activation calls. Instead you could listen to document opening

```
workspace.onDidOpenTextDocument((doc: TextDocument) => {
    if (doc.languageId == "JS" && doc.uri.scheme === "file") {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Yep.. needed the same functionality for `.ts` files.. works great with that listener

`if (doc.languageId === "typescript")`

. Not sure on the need for the `doc.uri.scheme`. Didn't seem available when I evaluated it.